# android post on twitter with http

Tags: java, android, http, twitter-fabric

I want to update status with **HTTP** request. I have used **Fabric API** to login with this code:

```
login = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.log);
login.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, twitterSessionResult.data.getUserName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {}
});
```

Now, how can I update status with HTTP?

Comment: Maybe off topic, but have you seen this https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose ? If you already have login to twitter, then it is most logic way to use TweetComposer to send tweet.. Just saying :-)

Comment: yes but i want to post without dialog and fabric can post without dialog but but cann't update image so i have to use HTTP